# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, seurat

I run this command in my Jupyter notebook:

library(Seurat)
library(dplyr)
library(qpcR)
library(clustree)

I detected the following error.

The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning this package
will retire shortly. Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports on
https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html for details.
This package is now running under evolution status 0

Attaching SeuratObject

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

```
filter, lag
```

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Warning message:
“package ‘qpcR’ was built under R version 4.1.3”
Loading required package: MASS

Warning message:
“package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 4.1.3”

Attaching package: ‘MASS’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

```
select
```

Loading required package: minpack.lm

Warning message:
“package ‘minpack.lm’ was built under R version 4.1.3”
Loading required package: rgl

Warning message:
“package ‘rgl’ was built under R version 4.1.3”
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘htmlwidgets’ 1.5.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required

Error: package ‘rgl’ could not be loaded
Traceback:

1. library(qpcR)
2. .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
3. stop(gettextf("package %s could not be loaded", sQuote(pkg)),
   .     call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

I try to install rgl (conda install -c r r-rgl) but I don't resolve the problem.

Comment: I think your problem is here: `namespace ‘htmlwidgets’ 1.5.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required`. So you need a newer version of `htmlwidgets`.